# Getting Started with RSpec v3 in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

Not your typical question to show on here but every tutorial seem to do this different. For most it works for them but for me, not.

I have a user model in my rails app and I have installed rspec. In my rails app dir, I ran:

```
rspec --init
```

created another folder: `/spec/models` and a file: `/spec/models/spec_user.rb`. In that file:

```
require 'user' # Does this requires my app/model/user.rb file??
```

In terminal when I ran `rspec spec/models`, I get: `cannot load such file -- user`

How can I get my `app/models/user.rb` to require in my rspec tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bunch of extra stuff that needs to be wired up when using rspec with rails, well if you want it to work right there is. I would recommend ditching the base rpsec gem in favor of [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails)

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

`bundle install`

`rails generate rspec:install`

That will create a `spec/rails_helper.rb` that wires up your environment for you. The docs can take you from there. Once you have rspec-rails installed and running, when you scaffold an object or use a rails generator the appropriate test files will be generated.

Comment: Thanks! I was working with ruby itself I never realized that I needed to install rspec for rails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your spec files to look like this:

```
modelname_spec.rb
```

and not vice versa